# How to find class in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am converting to slds to bootstrap in Lightning component. I am trying to display error message in bootstrap. It's working, but it displays very small font size. I did inspect element that time I got new class name ".form-element__help" for that error message. I just modified that font size. It displays message in bold format, but in my component that class isn't available? why?

I searched this class throughout my component. Isn't Avialbale? I just copied that class and apply the style in my css its working fine. How to find that class?

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <ui:inputText required="{!v.IsRequired}" aura:id="CompId" disabled="{!v.IsDisabled || v.IsReadOnly}" class="slds-input" placeholder="{!v.PlaceholderText}" change="{!c.handleOnChange}" value="{!v.Value}"/>
    </div>
```

Where is this class ".form-element__help"?[image]

Comment: That is added dynamically by salesforce whenever you make the UI component required. if you look at your screenshot it says 'Please enter a valid phone number'. Its added dynamically when a valid phone number is not entered. Its part of Lightning design system CSS. you can still override it in your component css as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below link in LDS website. it has the information

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/

bout Form Element

Error states alert the user when content in the form is invalid. The `.slds-has-error` class is placed on the `<div class="slds-form-element">`. Place the error message for the user in a `<span>` with the `.slds-form-element__help` class.

The native form elements, `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, `<input type='checkbox'>`, and `<input type='radio'>`, receive validation styling for disabled, checked, and checked disabled, if applicable.

The read-only state is for form elements that can’t be modified. It is used for small, non-editable form fields that sit next to inputs and allows the size and height to align. It is not meant for large paragraphs of text.

Because the read-only field state has no `<input>`, don’t use a `<label>` to provide better accessibility for screen readers and keyboard navigators. Instead, use a `<span>` with the `.slds-form-element__label` class. Instead of an `<input>`, use the `.slds-form-element__static` class inside the `.slds-form-element__control` wrapper.

Comment: Okay..how can i convert slds to bootstrap..it isnt easy approach...How can I do it any suggestion ???

Comment: you cannot do a like for like conversion from SLDS to bootstrap. bootstrap has its own grid system. rather look at the bootstrap documentation and use the components as you wish. I cant think of any tool which is readily available which can do this. Bootstrap documentation is pretty good so going through it should give you the jump start you need.

Comment: Already I designed slds..I want to convert it into boot strap.Iam facing problem so...